# No property found exception org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

This seems to be duplicate question, but I have not able to find the answer I am looking for and my issue is slightly different so please be patient before marking it down or duplicate -

I have a save and delete function which takes Book Class object to perform insert and delete operations and somehow spring is taking it as a property from Book class, is there any specific way to implement **insert** and **delete** operation when using CrudRepository that I am missing or something else, I have almost tried everything all the answers available here but none helped, please if you could guide me through this issue.

this is the exception I am facing currently with below given code -

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'booksController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'bookService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bookServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'booksDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'booksDao': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property book found for type Books!
```

**My Entity class**

```
package com.nerdbot.lms.model;

import java.sql.Timestamp;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Books {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long buid;
    private String book_Name;
    private String isbn;
    private String author;
    private boolean avialable;
    private String teachers_note;
    private String suid;
    private Timestamp return_date;
    private String meta_tags;
    private boolean award_winner;
    private String subject;
    private boolean banned_in_any_country;
    private String country_of_ban;
    private String aisle;

    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    public boolean isAvialable() {
        return avialable;
    }

    public void setAvialable(boolean avialable) {
        this.avialable = avialable;
    }

    public String getMeta_tags() {
        return meta_tags;
    }

    public void setMeta_tags(String meta_tags) {
        this.meta_tags = meta_tags;
    }

    public boolean isAward_winner() {
        return award_winner;
    }

    public void setAward_winner(boolean award_winner) {
        this.award_winner = award_winner;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public String getCountry_of_ban() {
        return country_of_ban;
    }

    public void setCountry_of_ban(String country_of_ban) {
        this.country_of_ban = country_of_ban;
    }

    public String getAisle() {
        return aisle;
    }

    public void setAisle(String aisle) {
        this.aisle = aisle;
    }

    public String getSuid() {
        return suid;
    }

    public void setSuid(String suid) {
        this.suid = suid;
    }

    public Long getBuid() {
        return buid;
    }

    public void setBuid(Long buid) {
        this.buid = buid;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getBook_Name() {
        return book_Name;
    }

    public void setBook_Name(String book_Name) {
        this.book_Name = book_Name;
    }

    public String getTeachers_note() {
        return teachers_note;
    }

    public void setTeachers_note(String teachers_note) {
        this.teachers_note = teachers_note;
    }

    public Timestamp getReturn_date() {
        return return_date;
    }

    public void setReturn_date(Timestamp return_date) {
        this.return_date = return_date;
    }

    public boolean isBanned_in_any_country() {
        return banned_in_any_country;
    }

    public void setBanned_in_any_country(boolean banned_in_any_country) {
        this.banned_in_any_country = banned_in_any_country;
    }

}
```

**My DAO interface**

```
package com.nerdbot.lms.dao;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.nerdbot.lms.model.Books;

@Repository
public interface BooksDao extends CrudRepository<Books, Long>{

    Iterable<Books> findAll();

    Iterable<Books> findBybuid(int buid);

    Iterable<Books> findByAuthor(String author);

    Iterable<Books> findByMeta_Tags(String meta_tags);

    Iterable<Books> findByBook_Name(String book_Name);

    Iterable<Books> findByIsbn(String isbn);

    Iterable<Books> findBySubject(String subject);


}
```

**My Service interface**

```
package com.nerdbot.lms.service;

import com.nerdbot.lms.model.Books;

public interface BookService {

    Iterable<Books> findAll();
    Iterable<Books> findBybuid(int buid);
    Iterable<Books> findByAuthor(String author);
    Iterable<Books> findByMeta_Tags(String meta_tags);
    Iterable<Books> findByBookName(String book_Name);
    Iterable<Books> findByIsbn(String isbn);
    Iterable<Books> findBySubject(String subject);
    void save( Iterable<Books> books);
    void save(Books book);
    void delete(Iterable<Books> books);
    void delete(Books book);

}
```

**My Rest Controller**

```
package com.nerdbot.lms.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.nerdbot.lms.model.Books;
import com.nerdbot.lms.service.BookService;

@RestController
public class BooksController {

    @Autowired
    BookService bookService;

    @RequestMapping("/getallbooks")
    public  Iterable<Books> getAllBooks(Model model) {

         Iterable<Books> books = bookService.findAll();

        model.addAttribute("books", books);

        return books;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addbook",headers = {
    "content-type=application/json" }, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void addBook(@RequestBody Books book) {
        bookService.save(book);

    }

    @RequestMapping("/getbyname")
    public  Iterable<Books> getBookByName(@RequestParam(value="bookName", defaultValue="all") String book_Name) {
        return bookService.findByBookName(book_Name);
    }

}
```

**Full Exception**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'booksController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'bookService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bookServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'booksDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'booksDao': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property book found for type Books!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at com.nerdbot.lms.LibraryManagementSystemApplication.main(LibraryManagementSystemApplication.java:15) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bookServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'booksDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'booksDao': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property book found for type Books!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'booksDao': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property book found for type Books!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property book found for type Books!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:309) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:272) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:243) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:247) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:398) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:378) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:89) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:64) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:103) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:214) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:77) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:436) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:221) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is with `Repository` method

```
Iterable<Books> findByBook_Name(String book_Name);
```

Please refer this [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions)

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions

We should avoid writing underscores as data members in JPA entities as `_` has special meaning in Spring JPA repository.

JPA is thinking that you have a property named `book` inside `Books` and you are traversing down to `book.name`

Comment: Thanks for your reply  but it isn't helping, I have replaced book_Name to bookName everywhere in entity, dao and service, it has still the same issue.

Comment: Are u still getting `No property book found for type Books!` OR it's some other property this time.
Have u changed `meta_tags`  to `metaTags` as well?

Comment: My bad, :) I was too quick to change one property and try , I got your point now. let me refactor all the properties to check.

Comment: I have added those underscores because H2 was creating multiple columns with and without underscores for camelCase properties and to avoid that I changed my properties to match it to H2 requirement.

Comment: You can use `@Column(name="book_name")` above the property.

Comment: awesome idea, I was thinking of the same :D

Answer (score 0):

Avoid underscores at the repository findByBook_Name. Beacuase JPA entities as _ have special meaning in Spring JPA repository.

```
Iterable<Books> findByBookName(String book_Name);
```